# How to check all the validations are passed in magento form?

Tags: magento-1.9, form-validation, billing

I want to check if all the validations are passed in magento billing form

**what i have tried** is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //<![CDATA[    
    var billingForm = new VarienForm('co-billing-form', true);
            if (billingForm.validator && billingForm.validator.validate())
            {
              //do the stuff
            }
     //]]>
    </script>
```

But it always returns true , even if all the validations are not passed ,

When i alerted the `billingForm.validator.validate()` it returns `true` .

how to get over it ?

Comment: Did you add the class names as defined to the input fields in that form? Check it out http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/

Answer (score 2):

This should be enough as this is what happens when the form is submitted.

```
submit : function(url){
    if(this.validator && this.validator.validate()){
         this.form.submit();
    }
    return false;
},
```

I would suggest that the validation is either set-up on items outside of the form or the validation is actually passing.

Comment: oaky , here `co-billing-form` is the billing form id , but its always returns true even filed are not validated